# How to migrate EFCore database from code with external migration assembly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1, assembly-loading

I am creating an application that includes IdentityServer4 using .NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core. It is intentended that it can target multiple database types.

Following various examples I have managed to get it working with both SQL Server and MySQL by using two separate migration assemblies in addition to the IdentityServer project itself which contains the DbContexts.

In Startup.cs I have the following:

```
var migrationsAssembly = $"IdentityServer.Migrations.{serverType}";

services.AddDbContext<Data.IdentityServerContext>(options =>
{
    switch (serverType)
    {
        case ServerType.SqlServer:
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            break;
        case ServerType.MySql:
            options.UseMySql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            break;
    }
});
```

Where ServerType is a configuration enum of either "SqlServer" or "MySql"

If I use the dotnet command line, the migrations work correctly

```
dotnet ef database update -c IdentityServerContext
```

I wish to be able to use configuration or a command line to get the IdentityServer to apply the migrations itself.

e.g. in Main()

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("migrateDatabases"))
        {
            var identityContext = provider.GetRequiredService<IdentityServerContext>();
            identityContext.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

host.Run();
```

However if I do this I get an exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'IdentityServer.Migrations.MySql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'IdentityServer.Migrations.MySql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly assemblyContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsAssembly..ctor(ICurrentDbContext currentContext, IDbContextOptions options, IMigrationsIdGenerator idGenerator, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 databaseFacade)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at IdentityServer.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The migration assembly is in the same directory as the project DLL and EXE.

What I cannot work out is **why** it is unable to load the migration assembly.

As an experiment I wired up the `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving` callback and used `Assembly.LoadFrom(<path>)` to load the assembly manually. This works and applies the migrations correctly, but is a very messy workaround.

Can anyone shed any light on why the assembly load fails when called from `context.Database.Migrate()`, but not when using the ef tools or when loaded manually in the `Resolving` callback?

---

*Edit*

I think I have found a workaround, that matches what we do in another project in the same solution.

We are dynamically loading modules into the Dot Net Core DI framework at runtime in that project, and the migrations in the modules appear to be working correctly.

I have added the `Scutor` library to the project to scan manually loaded migration assemblies into the DI services collection. Even though it does not register any classes, this appears to be enough to load the assembly into the `AssemblyLoadContext` so that the migration code is able to load it.

This does not however explain why it is unable to load the migration assemblies automatically.

Comment: Did you ever run that migration code block inside Startup configure method?

Comment: I have tried that, and it still does not work. In general it is recommended not to do database work in Startup which is why the code is between the `.Build()` and the `.Run()` methods in `Main()`. Both `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` will have been run by that point.